# how to send a letter as itself when it is used as hotkey in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

For example I want press 'v' to get 'asdfv' by autohotkey, but when I define like the below :

v::send asdfv

the script run into  an infinite loop, because the last v is covered as the shortcut. So the question is, how I can get want I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways:

```
#UseHook On

v::send asdfv
```

or

```
$v::send asdfv
```