# Autohotkey - Repetitive hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to send a letter as itself when it is used as hotkey in autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427010/how-to-send-a-letter-as-itself-when-it-is-used-as-hotkey-in-autohotkey)

When I try to run the script:

```
v::Send tv
```

it starts typing t repetitively.

And while playing with autohotkey I probably did something wrong and now it quits saying

> Error at line 1.
>
> Line Text: ; v::Send tv
>   Error : Invalid hotkey.
>
> The program will exit.

(I made it a comment using `;` later, the problem persisted before that.)

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I know it happens because the 'v' in tv sends a 't' and 'v' where the sent 'v' again sends 't' and 'v'. How to avoid this chain reaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hotkey is triggering itself when it sends a `v`. Try using `$`:

```
$v::Send tv
```

I'm not sure what caused it to say "Invalid hotkey".

Comment: So I guess this was a beginner's mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use:

```
:?*:v::tv ; * = no need to press enter, ? = will execute vene if letters have been typed before.
```

To avoid problems of not being able to use the letter v anywhere else, I normally use v\ this combination because it is easy and unique:

```
:?*:v\::tv
```

And if you want to limit the behaviour of the v key to just one application, I would use the AutoHotKey spy to get the application specific ID or name and place the hotkey inside an #ifwinactive. You will need to put SetTitleMatchMode, 2 at the top of your script. This sets the string mathing behaviour for functions like #ifwinactive. In this example v\ only works in Google Chrome.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#ifWinActive, Chrome ; limits the use of the following hotkey(s) to Chrome only.
    :?*:v\::tv
#ifWinActive
```